# def lvlup_all(lvl, exp): #lvl and exp not assigning to global variable

Tags: python

First of all i'm very new and stupid.

So I have a bunch of skills and I'm trying to make a single function to Level up, instead of creating 100 different identical functions.

Also if anyone knows how can i print `("Next EXP lvl: " + str(nextgoal))` and have `nextgoal` with no decimals and EXP the name of the global variable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and sorry for giving you a headache after reading this.

````
walking = 1
running = 1
eating  = 1
driving = 1
biking  = 1

walkingEXP = 160
runningEXP = 160
eatingEXP  = 160
drivingEXP = 160
bikingEXP  = 160

#now when i call function below i assign walking to lvl, after it doesnt update walking when function is done, walking should be 2 but stays 1

def lvlup_all(lvl, exp): #lvl and exp should be assigned to global variables after.
    nextgoal = 150 * lvl
    if exp >= nextgoal:
      lvl = lvl + 1
      print("LVL: " + str(lvl))
      print("Next EXP lvl: " + str(nextgoal))
    elif exp < nextgoal:
      print("small")
    else:
      print("oops") ```

my current output is this

LVL: 2 #from the piece of code above
Next EXP lvl: 150 #needs to be 150 * lvl

running lvl: 1 #global variables
walking lvl: 1 #global variables
````

Comment: 1) Update `nextgoal` after updating `lvl`; 2) return `lvl` and `exp` (or only `lvl`, since `exp` can't change) and assign it back to the global `lvl`; 3) do not set global vars from within the function if it can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cleanest way to do it then, if you have any questions let me know:

```
class Skill:
    EXP_TO_LVL_UP = 150

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.lvl = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.total_exp = 0

    def add_exp(self, exp_amount):
        self.total_exp += exp_amount
        self.exp += exp_amount
        if self.exp >= self.EXP_TO_LVL_UP:
            self.level_up()

    def level_up(self):
        while self.exp >= self.EXP_TO_LVL_UP:
            self.lvl += 1
            self.exp -= self.EXP_TO_LVL_UP

        print(f'Current LVL: {self.lvl}')
        print(f'Next lvl in: {self.EXP_TO_LVL_UP - self.exp}XP')


running = Skill(name='running')
print(f'Initial lvl: {running.lvl}')
print(f'Initial exp: {running.exp}')
print('-----')
print('After adding exp to skill:')
running.add_exp(200)

walking = Skill(name='walking')
skills = [running, walking]  # List of all skills
for skill in skills:  # for loop that checks if there is possibility to level up.
    skill.level_up()
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from elaboration. What was the OP doing wrong? _How_ does this fix it?